# Comparing characters in MIPS, and doing character arithmetic

Tags: mips

Basically, I want to compare two characters using a branching statement in MIPS. Although I am not really sure as to what instructions to use for this. Anyways I will show my pseudo code I wrote for it in C.

```
The array M contains characters.
if(M[i] >= "0" && M[i] <= "9")
{
    ascii_to_bin += M[i] - "0"
}
```

That is just one of the if statements, but it encapsulates every question I have at the moment. I don't know which instructions to use when making the comparison in the conditional statement. Furthermore, the line `$ascii_to_bin += M[i] - "0"`; do not really know how to do character arithmetic in MIPS.

Comment: I'm not 100% confident, which is why this is a comment rather than an answer, but I don't think MIPS (or any assembly language) has a notion of types. I'm pretty sure you can only do this by manipulating the ASCII value of the characters

Comment: What do you mean by manipulating the ASCII value?

Comment: Maybe I will make this an answer. Hang on

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, the only reason you can do arithmetic on characters in C (And C++, Java, etc.) is that `char` types can be implicitly converted into `int` types, via their ASCII value.

However, MIPS (And assembly languages more broadly) don't have a notion of types; any notion of a variable containing a "character" is imposed by the programmer, not by the machine.

So what does that mean? It means you're working with the integer value directly. If you pull what you know to be the character `a` from memory, you're *actually* working with the ASCII value instead, `97`. And you can compare that as if it were any other integer (Because it *is* any other integer).

So your if-statement will then look roughly like this (In pseudocode):

```
If M[i] >= 48 and M[i] <= 57 then:
  ascii_to_bin += M[i] - 48
```